# ClassCastException: getApplication() returns something weird

Tags: java, android

I have an Android application with a custom application class:

```
<application android:name=".App"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:description="@string/IDS_APPDESC"
    android:label="@string/IDS_APPTITLE"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.App">
```

Works in general. In the main activity's `onCreate`, I retrieve the app object:

```
public App App()
{
    return (App)getApplication();
}
```

Now, I've got several crash reports in Google Play console that say this line caused a `ClassCastException`. They originate on

- Huawei Honor 10 (HWCOL), Android 9.
- OnePlus OnePlus3T (OnePlus3T), Android 8.0

How's that possible?

The stack goes:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3300)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3484)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:86)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:108)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:68)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2123)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:207)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7470)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:524)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:958)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
  at ru.acme.Main.App (Main.java:322)
  at ru.acme.Main.onCreate (Main.java:145)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7436)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7426)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1286)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3279)
```

EDIT2: there's a method called App() which returns the application, and also a class App. The Java compiler doesn't complain...

EDIT3: got the same crash from another device/OS. Probably not hackery.

Comment: Can you post sample stack traces?

Comment: Your crash is coming from inside a `Main.App` class. That's not `.App`, unless your `package` attribute is strange in your manifest. Are you sure that `.App` is `Main.App`? IMHO, it feels like you have two things named `App`, and you might be running into problems in casting one `App` to another `App`.

Comment: Main.App() is the method, which is called from Main.onCreate(). Yes, there's a method App() which returns the application object of class App. It was never a problem before...

Comment: Oh, right, that's a method, sorry for my mistake. I was hoping the stack trace would show what was trying to be cast. It may be someone is playing with repackaging your app with a hacked `Application` subclass.

Comment: By necessity side loaded, I guess. Does Google Play pick up and report crashes from those?

Comment: Don't know the rules about that, sorry. I usually use another crash logger, integrated into the app, rather than Play's.

Comment: I hear you, the built-in reporting is meh. :) I have one for native signals, but not for uncaught Java exceptions. You gave me an idea though...

Comment: I see those from Android 9 (primarily) but also Android 6 and Android 8. Manufacturers are mainly Xiaomi and Asus. Perhaps bad OEM code?

Answer (score 1):

> During auto backup and restore operations, the system launches the app in a restricted mode to both prevent the app from accessing files that could cause conflicts and let the app execute callback methods in its `BackupAgent`. In this restricted mode, the app's main activity is not automatically launched, its Content Providers are not initialized, and the base-class `Application` is instantiated instead of any subclass declared in the app's manifest.
>
> Caution: To avoid errors, make sure that the parts of your app that execute in the restricted mode (mostly your `BackupAgent`) don't access content providers in the same app or attempt to cast the `Application` object. If you can't avoid those patterns, then consider implementing Key/Value backup or disabling backup entirely.
>
> – [`developer.android.com`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#ImplementingBackupAgent) via [Pablo Baxter](https://medium.com/@pablobaxter/what-happened-to-my-subclass-android-application-924c91bafcac)

Comment: Good find. The stack suggests, however, that the main activity is being created.

Comment: You’re right. This could only be the explanation for *your* crashes if you start an `Activity` manually at some point in the background. Otherwise, there would need to be yet another cause for these strange crashes.